# Chrome extensions alarms on system standby

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome Extension that should make some checks every 24 hours

```
var oneDayInMinutes = 24*60*60;
chrome.alarms.create('checkState', {periodInMinutes: oneDayInMinutes});
```

What happens to this alarm when the system goes to standby? Is it fired about 24h after it was set, it's shifted by the time the system was in standby mode or it's turned off or disabled in some way?

Comment: Relevant: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471524

Comment: FYI: The number you have as `oneDayInMinutes`, `24*60*60`, is actually the number of seconds in one day. The number of minutes in one day is `24*60`.

Comment: Whooops...that's right! But I also tried to use value like 30 and 60 directly. I think on Linux I have the same bug as described for OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *supposed* to fire at earliest 24h after it was set. If the time was missed, it should notice and fire anyway.

There is, however, [an open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471524) indicating that, at least in OS X and for short time periods after the system wakes, the alarm may be shifted by the time system was asleep. I suppose this corrects itself after a
while - but don't quote me on that.

You can work around the bug by listening to `chrome.idle` events and re-creating alarms after wake.

Comment: FYI: You did not complete your final sentence.